# Servlet File Uploading

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets, heap-memory, apache-commons-fileupload

I'm using a servlet to do a multiple file upload (using Apache Commons *FileUpload*). A portion of my code is posted below. My problem is that if I upload files again and again , the memory consumption of the app server jumps rather drastically. The Apache Tomcat server seems to hang on to the memory and never return it. The heap space runs out of memory. Sometimes it runs out of memory exception and throws `java heap space error`.

I closed all the input streams, I think the problem is in the `ServletFileUpload`, could anyone help me out to how to close it.

```
ServletContext context=this.getServletConfig().getServletContext();
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
FileCleaningTracker fileCleaningTracker = FileCleanerCleanup.getFileCleaningTracker(context);
factory.setFileCleaningTracker(fileCleaningTracker);

if (isMultiPart) {
    upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

    try {
        itr = upload.getItemIterator(request);
        while (itr.hasNext()) {

        item = itr.next();
        if (item.isFormField()) {
        ...
```

Comment: connect to the JVM with VisualVM and take a look what's taking the memory, I bet it won't be comons-upload stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You're using **FileCleaningTracker**, there are versions of Apache commons FileUpload with a bug in that component (see this: http://blog.novoj.net/2012/09/19/commons-file-upload-contains-a-severe-memory-leak/)

It seems it has been already fixed: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FILEUPLOAD-189

So try using the last available version.

Comment: Thanks...can u describe the use of DiskFileItemFactory ,and what haapens when I create a ServletFile Upload object without it

Comment: @user2535809 that's something that is better explained in the [Apache commons FileUpload documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) have a look at the user guide, streaming API and javadoc.